# Inverse scrolltop effect

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I would like to have a function that changes the opacity of div when I scroll down. For example, the more I scroll down, the more my divs appear more clearly and when I scroll back up, they do the opposite.

I found code that works well, but I want the opposite. A sort of "scrollBottom". Here's the code that I'm talking about:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".four").css({
      "opacity" : 1 - $(window).scrollTop()/1000})
    })
  })
```

I don't have any experience in Javascript, that's why I'm asking you guys! Thank you!

Comment: Java and Javascript are not the same thing.

Comment: Have you tried getting the document height, then calculate in reverse (so you're adding to 0 instead)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is the mathematical inverse: `0 + $(window).scrollTop() / 1000`

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $(".four").css({
    opacity: 0 + $(window).scrollTop() / 1000
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 2000px;
}

.four {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 25;
  left: 25;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="four">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
```

Comment: Uhmm... I doesn't work in my html. I don't know why. I put your code into my script section and I added $(document).ready(function() { } but that doesn't work either...

Comment: Oh, it work! I forggot to put this line: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

I'm sorry, I'm dumb lol! Thank you!!

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)